# Restrict python to use only the real number space

Tags: python, math, numbers

In python when doing something like `x=(-10)**(1/3)` i get a complex number. I instead want to only see the one real x value which in this case would be approx `-2.15`. Now I do understand that I could import a math library like mpmath and generate all solutions (3 in the case), loop through them and find the one thats real. Im looking for a more elegant solution as I want to be able to create a program thats able to take in any sort of function and plug numbers into it.

here's a bit of code demonstrating what im trying to do

```
f= lambda x:x**(1/3)
print(f(-10))
```

in this case i get a complex number representing one of the 3 possible roots, but i only want the real root

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga is their some sort of library that can do this globally? because I want the user inputted function to be "universal". Ive looked at mpmath, but they dont seem to have an inbuilt function to return only the real root, but instead id have to generate a list of roots and loop through them which is impractical for my situation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The real cube root of a negative number is the negative value of the positive number's cube root:

```
>>> def cube_root(x):
...     return -pow(-x,1/3) if x < 0 else pow(x,1/3)
...
>>> cube_root(10)
2.154434690031884
>>> cube_root(-10)
-2.154434690031884
```

Comment: id like to point out that this works for any odd root and that this solution does not work for negative roots, but its good enough for me so ive marked it as correct and upvoted

Comment: @MohammadAli Yes, but you your question only mentioned cube roots :^)

Comment: you are correct i was just leaving the comment incase others read your answer in the future

Answer (score 0):

I think this should be enough :)

```
def f(x):
    if x < 0: return -pow(-x, 1/3)
    return pow(x, 1/3)
```

Comment: Basically, square_root(squared(real part) + squared(imaginary part)) = | square_root(number) |